# Easy way to invoke standard mail client from c++ with recipient adress and subject?

Tags: c++, windows, email

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262451/how-do-i-programmatically-send-an-email-in-the-same-way-that-i-can-send-to-mail/262529#262529) from TcKs gave me an idea, thus i tried following:

```
system("mailto:thomas.muster@domainname.com?subject=Test");
```

and

```
    STARTUPINFO info = {sizeof(info)};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = {0};
    if (!::CreateProcess(NULL, "mailto:thomas.muster@domainname.com",
        NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
    {
        MessageBox("Couldn't invoke Standard Mail Client");
        return;
    }
```

But neither the first nor the second form did work. Do you have any simple solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you tried `CreateProcess`, I assume you're on Windows, so I added the relevant tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the ShellExecute function: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816

Comment: std::wstring mail = L"mailto:thomas.muster@domainname.com";
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", mail.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Opens a blank Chrome tab.